# How to redirect back to protected page after Nextauth successful login?

Tags: reactjs, next-auth

I am using NextAuth for auth

```
const options = {
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({...}),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: SIGN_IN_URL,
    verifyRequest: AUTH_URL,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session(session) {
      return { ...session }
    },
    async signIn({ user }) {
      const result = ...
      if (result) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I have a protected page `/dashboard`

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context)

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: SIGN_IN_URL,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

If an unauthorised user tries to access the page they get redirected to the sign in page `http://localhost:3000/auth/signin`
After successful login it redirects back to `/`.

But how do I set NextAuth up to redirect back to the originating page (in this case `/dashboard`) after successful log in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a `callbackUrl` in the query string. It should be a url encoded path like `%2Fdashboard`, for example in your snippet:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context)

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2Fdashboard",
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

Going to `/api/auth/signin` will use the custom signin page you specified in your nextauth config. To see this working in production, check out the official [nextauth example](https://next-auth-example.vercel.app/).